# Redirect all websites to a single webpage using iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, router, busybox

I have a router which runs busybox, it has iptables so i wanted to redirect all webpages clients request to a single webpage. I cant use hosts file because the `/etc` folder is mounted as read-only. Is it possible to do that using iptables? Im new to both linux and networking so please try to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform HTTP redirects, you need something that understands the HTTP protocol, which iptables does not. You'll need to install an HTTP-aware application (e.g. a webserver) that you can configure to perform your redirect.

Comment: the router has httpd if i use that

Comment: Don't do this on a router. Your router should be tasked with only routing/firewalling. Use a proper webserver.